# Publish empty sub folder in MVC5

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a ASP.Net MVC 5 application. In this application I have an "Images" folder. As a sub folder, I have a "logos" folder which will be filled out by the application when requested.

When I publish (on file system), the sub folder is NOT published.

How can I publish this empty folder (without having to add a "dummy" image)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last I knew there was no way around this, and the [VS team were aware](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/546356/publish-deploy-does-not-deploy-empty-folders). I get around it by putting an "empty" web.config in the folder.

Comment: The only way that I found to ensure that my "empty" folder was included in the output from publishing my application was to add something to the folder and mark it as content. I added a text file called "info.txt" that simply stated the purpose of the folder ("to temporarily contain images for processing item editing"). Now the folder and text file are included in the published output.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the need to publish an Empty folder,
Why not just try and create the folder on startup (or when needed)?

`System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/images"));`

It is not even needed to check if it pre-exists as the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) suggest

> Any and all directories specified in path are created, unless they
>   already exist or unless some part of path is invalid. The path
>   parameter specifies a directory path, not a file path. If the
>   directory already exists, this method does nothing.

Comment: Then the executing context user needs to have permissions to create the folder. They should not according to our company policy.

Comment: Your context user on startup is the application, not the user.
The application pool already has permissions.

Comment: Nope. That gave an error. Application pool did not have access. I had to add that web.config in order to fix this.